# If Statement Vs. while loop

Tags: performance, if-statement, while-loop

I readied some where that while loops are faster than if Statement;

Doesn't That Make

```
while(something)
{
    //the code
    break;
}
```

faster and better than a normal If Statement ??!

If true why people uses the if statements 'till now <-- I had to use a while loop right there : )

Thanks.

Comment: "while statements" represents loops and runs many times and depends condition. A mistake in code will be drop you infinite loops. "If statements" are run deterministic , not loop like. That means, your comparison will be different output for different cases.  Could you share some code for this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally **not faster** in natively compiled languages like C, C++, Rust, etc. since the optimizing compilers can rewrite this anyway but basic one may not (resulting in more branches. It is *bug prone* due to the `break` and does not **make the intent clear** resulting in a *less readable code*. Put it shortly: *do not use this code* to emulate conditions. Instead, *write clean codes*, check that the compiler does its optimizing job correctly, and *only then*, use micro-optimization to speed up your code if your **profiler** show this is needed and worth it. As Donald Knuth said once: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*.